# Photo Tilt background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, tilt

Just found this neat tool that replicates Facebook Paper's photo tilt feature for the web: https://github.com/tregoning/photoTilt

I'd like to apply this to an image set as my background:

```
 body {background-image: url('../img/background.png');}
```

Comment: works on a image in a container, not on background images
http://jt.io/2014/photo-tilt/

Comment: In that case, is there any way to add text on top of the container? @Grumpy